# Python script with SimpleCV: set format image

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, simplecv

I'm using a Raspicam with the SimpleCV framework, when I work on the SimpleCV Shell everything work well. When i work with Python script I have some problems.

When I launch a python script like this:

```
from SimpleCV import * 
cam = Camera(0)
screen = cam.getImage().rotate(180)
screen.save("Code/SimpleCV/SimpleCV/app/screen2.jpg")
```

everything work.

But when i set the format 1280X1024 with a code like this:

```
from SimpleCV import * 
cam = Camera(0, {"width":1280, "height":1024})
screen = cam.getImage().rotate(180)
screen.save("Code/SimpleCV/SimpleCV/app/screen2.jpg")
```

I receive this error:

```
ERROR: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "Code/SimpleCV/SimpleCV/app/getimm.py", line 5, in <module>
     cam.getImage().save("Code/SimpleCV/SimpleCV/app/screen2.jpg")
   File "/home/pi/Code/SimpleCV/SimpleCV/Camera.py", line 618, in getImage
     cv.GrabFrame(self.capture)
 TypeError: Expected CvCapture for argument 'capture'
```

Thanks